# how to limit memory for edgeAgent on an Edge device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge

I have found out from Azure team that the memory limit for Edge modules including `edgeHub` can be controlled by specifying `createOptions -> HostConfig -> Memory`.  How to control memory limit for `edgeAgent` Docker container as it is created by `edgeAgent`? Is this documented? Currently here it shows as 1.88GB on a 2GB VM.

Below is an extract from `docker stats`

```
fd66aaa4dbe1        edgeAgent                 0.01%               40.59MiB / 1.885GiB   2.10%               2.18MB / 1.13MB     55.6MB / 705kB      15
```

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as accepted.  If it does not work for you, please provide some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the memory limit is not specific to the edgeHub module but it is the same for any other docker module used with IotEdge.  You can add the Memory setting to the HostConfig section in the createOptions of any module.

For the edgeAgent the deployment setting would look like this:

```
"systemModules": {
          "edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\":{\"Memory\":536870912}}"
            }
          },
          "edgeHub": {
          ...
          }
        }
```

With this do a new deployment.

For the changes to take affect on your machine you have to remove the edgeAgent module so it will create a new one according to your changed deployment rules.
You can do so with the following command:

> sudo docker rmi mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0 -f

After that restart the iotEdge Deamon with

> sudo systemctl restart iotedge

After that the memory will be limited for the edgeAgent module.

Note:
If you want to limit memory on a Raspberry Pi, be aware that memory limit support is turned off by default. You can find a HowTo for enabling it here: https://blog.raveland.org/post/docker_raspian/

Comment: i have tried providing following and had no effect `"edgeAgent": {
            "type": "docker",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azureiotedge-agent:1.0",
              "createOptions": "{\"HostConfig\": { \"Memory\": \"536870912\" }}"
            }
          },
`

Comment: The value of "Memory" is an int not a string.  Try removing the quotes around the value.

Comment: I tried changing memory value to be of type integer and it does not have any effect. My assumption is `/usr/bin/iotedged` starts `edgeAgent` and it does not read device twin.

Comment: The edgeAgent module has to be recreated after you changed the deployment settings.  I adjusted my answer accordingly.  I just tried it on a virtual machine and it does work !

Comment: why the edgeAgent Docker image need to be removed? is not limiting memory a setting when container is launched?

Comment: Did you follow the described steps?  Did it limit the memory for edgeAgent?

Comment: yes it did after i removed the edgeAgent image. can you explain why deletion of image is required?